# Iterate values of var_1, var_2 var_3 ... var_n

Tags: python, loops, variables

```
var_1 = 5
var_2 = 6
var_3 = 7

for i in range(3):

    string = "var_{}".format(i+1)
```

string will be var_1, var_2 and var_3
how would I replace them with 5, 6  and 7?

Comment: Do not make separate variables like that in the first place, instead use a list or dict to store all the values and then you can look them up using the `i` value as an index.

Comment: Yes you're totally right.
But my question is about handling this case if exists